# Weird keyboard bug on Latin American layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, 19.10

I am having a strange keyboard bug. Basically, this is a Dell XPS 15 with a latin american layout. I have it configured as such and all keys seems to work as expected except for the "< / >" key (placed on top of the Fn key).

[image: keyboard layout]

When I type that key, the char that appears on screen is the "\" char. Using the shift key shows the "|" char. Nevertheless, when I show the keyboard layout on screen, it shows the correct chars.

Already tried with the rest of Latin American layouts, but none match. Any suggestions?

Update 2020-04-01: As requested, the result for `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` the command is the following:

```
[('xkb', 'us+alt-intl'), ('xkb', 'latam')]
```

Comment: That sounds like the _English (UK)_ keyboard layout or something; the _Spanish (Latin American)_ layout should result in '<' and '>' respectively. Can you please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: Added the result for the command. The US keyboard layout is there, but I have the latin america layout activated. I can see that the rest of the keys match without a problem, but the less than key still generates the "\" char.

Comment: Removed the US keyboard layout and the key started working as expected. Added the US layout and the key keeps working. Now, if I move to the US layout, the issue appears again. But I can move back to the Latin American layout and it works correctly again. Previously, even when Latin America was selected, the key did not work. Is this a bug?

Comment: The variant of US keyboard layout you are using should behave as you describe. Possibly the basic _English (US)_ layout would fit your needs better. A bug? Well, considering that it works as expected now, I'd say it was a "temporary glitch". ;)

Comment: Well, I restarted and tried installing several different layouts and nothing worked until I uninstalled and installed again the US layout. I think this may be a bug but there is a simple workaround for it :)

Comment: Is the "Use the same source for all windows" option selected in Settings -> Region & Language -> Input Sources?

Comment: Yes, it was selected.